# Search results showing nodes which are already under NODE_ACCESS_DENY

Tags: 7, nodes, users, search

In Drupal 7, I have some nodes that are restricted access for anonymous user. I implemented this using `hook_node_access` where if the `user_is_anonymous` and if the operation is `View`, I am giving `NODE_ACCESS_DENY`.

Now, how can I restrict these pages from showing in search results page for anonymous user?

Answer (score 0):

You must flush the search cache after you have changed node access records.